# Approximate the following series $\sum_{k=11}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\ 3^k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to estimate the following serie.

$$\sum_{k=11}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\ 3^k}$$

I am thinking about comparison, but I am stuck.

It doesn't give a clear answer. It does look like a combined arithmetic and geometric serie.

Comment: Why approximate it, when you can evaluate it in closed form?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Write the Taylor series of $$\log \Big(1 - \frac{1}{3}\Big)$$

ant subtract by $s_{10}$.

Comment: How could you see that I should expand that serie?

Comment: Because of the sum you've presented. Notice that $$\log (1 - x) = - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $$\ln (1-x) = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}$$

By the Taylor series expansion. Hence $$-\ln (1-x) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k} $$

Now we set $x = 1/3$ :
$$-\ln (1-1/3) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1/3)^k}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^k\cdot k}$$

Therefore the sum from $k=1$ to $\infty$ = $-\ln (2/3) = \ln (3/2)$. However your sum starts at $k=11$ so we need to remove the first $10$ terms of the sum :
$$
\sum_{k=11}^\infty \frac{1}{3^k\cdot k} = \ln (3/2) - \sum_{k=1}^{10}\frac{1}{3^k\cdot k}
$$
This can be evaluated using [WA](http://tinyurl.com/zt9gw38).

Comment: Use \ln x fro lnx, \sin x for sinx and.... basically any function that is composed of multiple letters.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the series

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k+10}=x^{10}(1-x)^{-1}$$

we obtain by integration

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac13\right)^{k+11}}{k+11}=\int_{x=0}^{1/3}x^{10}(1-x)^{-1}dx=B\left(\frac13;11,0\right)$$
where $B$ is the incomplete Beta function.

(As shown in other posts, a closed-form with elementary functions exists.)

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't specify what is meant by "approximate", but I would note that none of the current answers lead directly to an approximation—yes, we can directly calculate the sum to be equal to $\ln(\frac{3}{2}) - \frac{20111503}{49601160}$ but how exactly are we planning to estimate *that*?

This is a job for Taylor's theorem.  The sum in question is just $R_{10}(\frac{1}{3})$, where $R(x) = f(x) - P_{10}(x)$ is the tenth remainder in the Taylor series for $f(x) = -\ln(1-x)$.

Taylor's theorem (specifically, the Lagrange form of the remainder) tells us that $R_{10}(\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{f^{(11)}(\zeta)}{11!}\left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^{11}$ for some $\zeta\in [0,\frac{1}{3}]$.  Since $f^{(11)}(x) = \frac{10!}{(1-x)^{11}}$, with maximum value $10! \cdot \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{11}$ in this interval, we arrive at:

$$R_{10}(\frac{1}{3}) \leq \frac{1}{11} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{11} < 5\cdot 10^{-5}$$

The true value is about $7\cdot 10^{-7}$, so this is correct to four decimal places.